# Cannot Add Data for the Second Time in Database but The First One Successful Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 views file for each 2 forms in one page , i can successfully add data from first form to database and read it but when i tried in second views, it gives `419 | PAGE EXPIRED` error. I use same code i used in first views to add data.

this is my routes :

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => 'atribut',
  'as' => 'atribut.'
], function () {

Route::group(['prefix' => 'tabHome', 'as' => 'tabHome.'], function () {
 Route::get('', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'showTab'])->name('showTab');
    
 Route::post('addDataFirst', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataFirst'])->name('addDataFirst');
 Route::get('deleteDataFirst/{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteDataFirst'])->name('deleteDataFirst');

 Route::post('addDataSecond', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'addDataSecond'])->name('addDataSecond');
 Route::get('deleteDataSecond/{id}', [AtributDashboardController::class, 'deleteDataSecond'])->name('deleteDataSecond');
 });
});
```

This is my method in controller to add data:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->inpDataFirst = new inpDataFirst ();
    $this->inpDataSecond = new inpDataSecond ();
}

public function addDataFirst()
{
    $data = [
        'name' => Request()->nameForm,
        'address' => Request()->addressForm,
    ];
    $this->inpDataFirst->addData($data);
    return redirect('atribut/tabHome');
}

public function addDataSecond()
{
    $data = [
        'name' => Request()->nameForm,
        'address' => Request()->addressForm,
    ];
    $this->inpDataSecond->addData($data);
    return redirect('atribut/tabHome');
}
```

in first view i have form action :

```
{{route('frontend.atribut.tabHome.addDataFirst')}}
```

and in second view i have form action :

```
{{route('frontend.atribut.tabHome.addDataSecond')}}
```

the form is in same page but different views file, that's why i use `return redirect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

419 error is shown when csrf token is mismatched add **@csrf** to your form